# What can i change to set correct paths for package modules?

Tags: python, path

I have a bot project, here is its structure, [image: structure]

when I add it to the server I get an error, [image: error]

but on my home computer everything works fine, and with such imports [image: imports]

I tried changing the file directories but that didn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this code to userbot.py and it helped to find the modules

```
from os.path import dirname, abspath
d = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:- `import sys; sys.path.append("..")` (assuming this error comes from main.py)